# I am not able to draw after clear my jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, drawing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class Cliente extends JPanel {
    private JButton adelanteButton;
    private JButton undoButton;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panelDibujo;

    private Rectangulo rectangulo = new Rectangulo();
    Originator originator;
    Caretaker caretaker;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Patron Memento");
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        frame.setContentPane(cliente.panel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Memento m : caretaker.history) {
            System.out.println("forcitooooooo");
            dibujar(m.getState(), Color.GREEN);
        }
    }

    public Cliente() {

        caretaker = new Caretaker();
        originator = new Originator();
        createUIComponents();
        undoButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            caretaker.anterior();
            panelDibujo.repaint();
        });

        panelDibujo.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelDibujo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));

        panelDibujo.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                MousePressedEvent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                MouseReleasedEvent(e);
            }

        });
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
    }

    private void MousePressedEvent(MouseEvent e){
        rectangulo.setX1(e.getX());
        rectangulo.setY1(e.getY());
    }

    private void MouseReleasedEvent(MouseEvent e){
        rectangulo.setX2(e.getX());
        rectangulo.setY2(e.getY());
        originator.setState(rectangulo);
        dibujar(rectangulo, Color.orange);
        caretaker.addMemento(originator.CreateMemento());
        rectangulo = new Rectangulo();
    }

    public void dibujar(Rectangulo r, Color c) {
        Graphics g = panelDibujo.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(c);
        g.drawRect(r.getX1(), r.getY1(), r.getX2() - r.getX1(), r.getY2() - r.getY1());
        g.dispose();
    }

}
```

Hello i am applying the memento pattern by using a jpanel and drawing some rectangles inside, right now my code is working fine about drawing with the mouse events, but the issue is when i try to undo. My logic so far is clear the jpanel and redo all the rectangles minus the last one.
But after clearing my jpanel is not drawing again :( can someone help me to fix it? thank you

Caretaker.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Caretaker {
    LinkedList<Memento> history;
    int indice;

    public Caretaker(){
        history = new LinkedList<>();
        indice = 0;
    }

    void addMemento(Memento m){
        if (history.size() == indice || history.isEmpty()){
            indice++;
            history.add(m);
        }else {
            indice = history.size()-1;
            history.subList(indice +1, history.size()).clear();
        }
    }

    Memento anterior(){
        if (history.size() > 0){
            indice--;
            return history.removeLast();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay mas wey!");
        return null;
    }

    Memento siguiente(){
        if (indice < history.size()+1){
            indice++;
            return history.get(indice+1);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay mas wey!");
        return null;
    }

    public void redibujar(JPanel f){
        Graphics g = f.getGraphics();

        for (Memento m: history) {
            g.drawRect(m.getState().getX1(), m.getState().getY1(), m.getState().getX2() - m.getState().getX1(), m.getState().getY2() - m.getState().getY1());
            g.dispose();
        }

    }

    public void clear(){
        history.clear();
        indice = 0;
    }
}
```

Memento.java

```
public class Memento {
    Rectangulo state;

    /*
    Constructor, unica manera de mandar/crear/guardar los datos
     */
    public Memento(Rectangulo state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Memento(){
        state = new Rectangulo();
    }

    Rectangulo getState(){
        return state;
    }
}
```

Originator.java

```
public class Originator {
    Rectangulo state;

    public void setState(Rectangulo rectangulo){
        this.state = rectangulo;
    }

    public Memento CreateMemento(){
        return new Memento(state);
    }

    public void setMemento(Memento m) {
        setState(m.getState());
    }
}
```

Rectangulo.java

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Rectangulo {
    private int x1;
    private int x2;
    private int y1;
    private int y2;

    

    Rectangulo(){
    }

    public Rectangulo(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public void setX1(int x1) {
        this.x1 = x1;
    }

    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }

    public void setX2(int x2) {
        this.x2 = x2;
    }

    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }

    public void setY1(int y1) {
        this.y1 = y1;
    }

    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }

    public void setY2(int y2) {
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawRect(this.getX1(), this.getY1(), this.getX2() - this.getX1(), this.getY2() - this.getY1());
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem is that this is not how you should be using graphics in Swing. You should not be calling `.getGraphics()` on components and using that Graphics object. Rather use the one passed into your paintComponent method.

Comment: What *exact* behavior are you trying to elicit?

Comment: Note that none of us can reproduce your program's misbehavior given your current code since we cannot compile nor run it. Consider condensing it to the smallest runnable code that reproduces your problem, a [mre].

Comment: I added all the code needed to run it. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Nope. Your code throws a NullPointerException due to uninitialized objects in the GUI, such as the undoButton and others

Comment: Plus other issues. Please fix. Also, again please tell the details of your code and your problem. Please go through the [ask] and the [tour] links.

Comment: I just updated the code, i refactor a bit.
My issue is: after clearing the jpanel i am not able to draw again inside the jpanel, is just cleared and not going for the paintComponent()

Comment: Test ***the posted code*** in isolation first to make sure that it compiles and runs. You're not doing this most important step.

Comment: I just tested in a new project and and has no errors now.

Comment: You are not testing the posted code. For instance, your undoButton still throws a NullPointerException, since nowhere in your posted code do you initialize it with an object (e.g., nowhere in the code above do you have `undoButton = new JButton():`). Again, you need to test the code that you've posted, separate from the code that you already have on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, you're not drawing correctly. You are trying to render using a JPanel, cliente, that is never added to the GUI, and you're trying to use a Graphics object that is extracted from this unrendered component, making the Graphics object thus obtained short-lived and unstable.

Instead, do all drawing in the paintComponent method. You can use a BufferedImage and draw that in paintComponent if desired, especially if you want images with objects that show different colors, or you can use your List (here a LinkedList, but ArrayList will work) and draw in paintComponent. For instance, something simple like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Cliente2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int BI_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int BI_HEIGHT = 650;
    private Rectangle drawingRect = null;
    // private java.util.List<Rectangulo> rectangulos = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Rectangulo2> rectangulos = new ArrayList<>();
    private JButton clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");

    public Cliente2() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);

        clearBtn.addActionListener(e -> clear());
        add(clearBtn);
    }

    private void clear() {
        rectangulos.clear();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(BI_WIDTH, BI_HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (drawingRect != null) {
            g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            g2.draw(drawingRect);
        }

        for (Rectangulo2 rectangulo : rectangulos) {
            rectangulo.draw(g2);
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Point p0;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            p0 = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            drawingRect = createDrawingRect(e);
            repaint();
        }

        private Rectangle createDrawingRect(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p1 = e.getPoint();
            int x = Math.min(p0.x, p1.x);
            int y = Math.min(p0.y, p1.y);
            int width = Math.abs(p0.x - p1.x);
            int height = Math.abs(p0.y - p1.y);
            return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            // lets create some random colors:
            float hue = (float) Math.random();
            float brightness = (float) Math.random();
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, brightness);

            Rectangulo2 rectangulo = new Rectangulo2(color, p0, e.getPoint());
            rectangulos.add(rectangulo);
            drawingRect = null;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Patron Memento");
        
        // Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        // frame.setContentPane(cliente.panel1);
        
        frame.add(new Cliente2());
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
class Rectangulo2 {
    private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
    private Color color;
    private Point p0, p1;

    public Rectangulo2() {
    }

    public Rectangulo2(Color color, Point p0, Point p1) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
        this.p0 = p0;
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public Point getP0() {
        return p0;
    }

    public Point getP1() {
        return p1;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2.setColor(color);
        int x = Math.min(p0.x, p1.x);
        int y = Math.min(p0.y, p1.y);
        int width = Math.abs(p0.x - p1.x);
        int height = Math.abs(p0.y - p1.y);
        g2.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        g2.setStroke(STROKE);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
        g2.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, i am new in java, i learned a lot from your code, one little stuff, using your code how i can undo last rectangle?